# Spring autowire of classes in dependant jar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring-hibernate feature built as a separate jar (Collection.jar) for use by multiple webapps. This collection.jar has a spring-config.xml where beans are defined. When this jar is included in a webapp (spring-application1), the classes defined in collection.jar are not getting auto-wired.

spring-config.xml from Collection.jar

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.antk.pkg" />

<import resource="spring-datasource.xml" />

<bean id="delegator" class="com.antk.pkg.Delegator">
    <property name="dbUtils" ref="dbUtils" />
</bean>


<bean id="dbUtils" class="com.antk.pkg.util.DBUtils">
    <property name="dao" ref="collectorDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="collector" class="com.antk.pkg.Collector">
    <property name="collectorService" ref="collectorServiceImpl" />
</bean>

<bean id="collectorServiceImpl" class="com.antk.pkg.service.CollectorService">
    <property name="collectorDao" ref="collectorDaoImpl" />
    <property name="delegator" ref="delegator" />
</bean>
...
```

and in spring-application1, I am including the above as :

```
<bean id="com.antk.pkg.collector.spring"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" abstract="false"
    scope="prototype" lazy-init="default" autowire="default">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>spring-config.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But when I call collector, collectorservice is being set as null all the time. Its not getting autowired. Any thoughts.

Comment: have you added this spring-config on your application settings web.xml ?

Comment: as @JorgeCampos suggests.  Just be cause spring-config.xml is present on the classpath does not mean it will be loaded by Spring.  You need to import it _somewhere_.  somewhere being: your application context or your dispatch servlet context

Comment: I missed the import code earlier. Now I have added it. I am already importing the spring-config.xml in the applications applicationContext file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your spring-config.xml to be present in your classpath.
Put below in your web.xml -
1) Specify which spring config files to load

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath*:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

2) Define the ContextLoaderListener :-

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Also there is a problem while loading spring-config.xml files from jar. 
" **Resource implementation supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for classpath resources which reside in a jar and have not been expanded (by the servlet engine, or whatever the environment is) to the filesystem.**"  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Avoid relying on classpath resource loader while loading config.xml files from jar.